# Parsing this CSV file in Groovy Grails

Tags: parsing, groovy, grails-2.0

I have a CSV file which I need to parse and display the content in a tabular form in JSP. The CSV file looks like

> Heading1 Heading2 Heading3 Heading4 Heading5 Heading6 
>   data11 data12 data13 data14 data15 data16 
>   data21 data22 data 23 data24 data25 data26

i.e, the CSV file has the first row as headings and the rest of the rows as corresponding data for the headings.
The controller code I have for this is as shown:

```
 file.eachLine{ line ->
                   // if the line is not blank
                   if(line.trim()){
                       // split the line at every space(s)

                       def value = line.split('\\s+').collect{it.trim()}
```

This works well for most of the data.
 But in some cases, there is a space inside the data it self. Say "heading3" has data like "Sample Data", this is taken as 2 different data and is throwing off the table displayed.
 How can I tweak this code for my intended purpose. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I've found it much easier to use a library for CSV parsing, rather than figuring out the do's and don'ts by myself. E.g.: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you for the tip Steinar, but my question is regarding this specific file, where there may be different conditions for parsing in the same file. The openCSV has generic methods . It did not help in this situation.

Comment: 3rd party libs are not always applicable. If I understand you correctly, you're using space as separator (not tab). How do you distinguish data containing a space from a space separator? Do you enclose data in quotation marks? E.g. something like: data11 data12 "data 13" data14

Comment: No I dont have quotation marks, and that is the problem. The CSV file is a client's file which doesn't follow a standard protocol. I am stuck with however the files has been given to me and I need tweak my code appropriately, hence the difficulty.

Comment: There's no good way of parsing the file... Even by hand, it sounds like you'd struggle in its current form